# Uninstalling and reinstalling .NET

Tags: windows, .net-framework

I need to fix a bunch of servers with .NET patch errors. Would uninstalling .NET affect any running applications? The Cleanup Tool doesn't removed any base .NET parts in the OS, just installs on top.

Comment: "Running applications"... would you operate on a car, taking out various belts and widgets, while it was driving on a highway?

Answer (score 0):

> Would uninstalling .NET affect any running applications?

Yes, of course. It will affect any software that depends on the .NET framework.

Comment: I'm upvoting to reverse a downvote.  The question is straightforward, MichaelBay's answer is straightforward, and I have direct experience of it being correct.  OP has to know which versions of .NET the various apps are dependent on before uninstalling any of the .NET versions.

Comment: Is there anyway to determine which running apps are dependent on which version of .NET?

Comment: @vitalsign0 Research the requirements of each .NET program you have installed

Comment: That's not practical. We are talking about thousands of servers.